# Call useEffect on button click

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to refactor the code here:

```
    useEffect(async() => {
        const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/user/usergroup', {withCredentials:true})
        setUserData(response.data) 
     }, [])


    const groupFilter = async(groupid) => {
        const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/user/usergroupfilter', {id:groupid}, {withCredentials:true})
        setUserData(response.data)
    }


  const loadAll = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/user/usergroup', {withCredentials:true})
        setUserData(response.data) 
      }
```

On the initial load, the page will load all users regardless of group they belong to. The page has some buttons that when clicked, will call the groupFilter function and display the user belongs to the group.

I also have a button called All, and when clicked on the loadAll function, it will load all users and the code is the same as useEffect. I am thinking is there a way to combine useEffect and loadAll as one so that I would not have repeating code? Or is there a way I can call the useEffect on the All button click?  Greatly appreciate any helps and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap the post and setState code in a function and call it from both places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const fetchAll = React.useCallback(async() => {
  const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/user/usergroup', {
    withCredentials: true
  })
  setUserData(response.data)
}, [])

useEffect(async() => {
  await fetchAll()
}, [fetchAll])
```

And call `fetchAll` while you click the All button.

Comment: The above method seems to output `destroy() is not a function` in more recent version. This link should fix the problem with modification: [React 18 - destroy is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769990/react-18-destroy-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom hook and call it whenever you need it.

```
 import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';  
    
    export default function useUSerData() {
        const [data,setData] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(async() => {
            const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/user/usergroup', {withCredentials:true})
            setData(response.data) 
         }, [])
    
         return data; 
    }
          
        
        
        useEffect(async() => {
            setUserData(useUSerData()) 
         }, [])
    
    
        const groupFilter = async(groupid) => {
            const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/user/usergroupfilter', {id:groupid}, {withCredentials:true})
            setUserData(response.data)
        }
    
    
      const loadAll = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setUserData(useUSerData()) 
          }
```