# Runtime Error ('destroy is not a function' )after upgrading from React V16 to 18

Tags: runtime-error, react-18

I've got the below error after ugrading react v18 from v16
[Screenhot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzAJh.png)

The project had useNavigate with .push method, had changed that to the below

`const navigate = useNavigate(); navigate('/url')`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could this be the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769990/react-18-destroy-is-not-a-function